# Caliburn Micro action bindings

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I want to call CanExpressionSave method when any of binded parameters are changed

Bindings are set using long syntax in caliburn micro.

```
<controls:ImageButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Image="/Resources/Save.png" AlternativeImage="/Resources/SaveDisabled.png" 
                      Text="Save" Style="{StaticResource ControlButtonStyle}" x:Name="ExpressionSave">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ExpressionSave">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=firsttag, Path=Text}"></cal:Parameter>
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=firstoperation, Path=Content}"></cal:Parameter>
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=secondtag, Path=Text}"></cal:Parameter>
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=SecondOperation, Path=Content}"></cal:Parameter>
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=thirdtag, Path=Text}"></cal:Parameter>
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:ImageButton>
```

Codebehind:

```
        public void ExpressionSave(string firsttag, string firstoperation, string secondtag,
        string secondoperation, string thirdtag){ }

    public bool CanExpressionSave(string firsttag, string firstoperation, string secondtag,
        string secondoperation, string thirdtag){}
```

Comment: Have you raised a property changed notification for these properties when they change? Either by implementing `INotifyPropertyChange` or inheriting from `Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase` in your VM and calling `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SomeProperty);`

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I found the error but can't answer my question before 8 hours :)

Comment: Problem was in few casings in bindings.

I thought i was getting the right data from parameters because i expected no values but the values i got where because of wrong bindings.

The xaml and the code above are valid, as CanExpressionSave will be binded implicitly by Caliburn. This means any change to any of the binded properties will trigger CanExpressionSave.

Hope this helps to someone :)

Comment: Always helps to keep an eye out on the debug window as you get your data binding exceptions in there by default (assuming you aren't using VS Express). I often miss them and scratch my head as bindings aren't the easiest thing to debug!

Comment: Yes, I should definitely get into habbit of checking output window. If i checked it first i would spot this immediately :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in few casings in bindings.

I thought i was getting the right data from parameters because i expected no values but the values i got where because of wrong bindings.

The xaml and the code above are valid, as CanExpressionSave will be binded implicitly by Caliburn. This means any change to any of the binded properties will trigger CanExpressionSave.

Hope this helps to someone :)